# Why is this script only applying to one of the list items on this list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a list with list elements that can be swiped revealing a delete button similar to the swipe delete effect in ios apps. I came across this perfect example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPQBWj). It uses the hammer.js library, css, and html. There are two list items in this demo and the first one can be dragged or swiped to the left revealing the delete button. The second li element regardless of sharing the same classes, can not be dragged to the left. I've tried changing the code a bit but can't seem to figure out why the swipe effect is only being applied to the first li element and not the second. Ultimately, I would like this effect to be applied to all li elements in my list. I'm probably missing something small but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly. I would appreciate it if someone can let me know.

The code:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="messages">
    <li>
        <div class="message">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <time datetime="2014-08-22">Friday</time>
        </div>
        <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="messages">
    <li>
        <div class="message">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <time datetime="2014-08-22">Friday</time>
        </div>
        <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>


<style>
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica  Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
}



.messages {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
padding:0;
}

.messages li {
position:relative;
list-style-type:none;
min-height:75px;
}

.messages li:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:28px;
height:1px;
background-color:#e6e6e8;
}

.message {
position:relative;
z-index:2;
display:block;
padding:8px 28px 28px 28px;
background-color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
}

.message:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:12px;
right:14px;
width:9px;
height:13px;

}

.message * {
-moz-user-select:none;
 }

.message h3 {
 margin:0 0 3px 0;
 color:#000;
 font-size:16px;
 letter-spacing:.15px;
 }

 .message p {
 margin:0;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#8e8e93;
 letter-spacing:.8px;

 }

 .message time {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 right:31px;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#8e8e93;
 letter-spacing:.8px;
 }

 .button-delete {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:82px;
 margin:0;
 border:none;
 background-color:#ff3b30;
 color:#fff;
 font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
 letter-spacing:.4px;
 }
 </style>





 <script>
 var transformStyle = prefix() + 'Transform',
 transitionStyle = prefix() + 'Transition',
 message = document.querySelector('.message'),
 buttonDelete = document.querySelector('.button-delete'),
 hammer = new Hammer(message, {dragLockToAxis: true,      dragBlockHorizontal: true}),
 min = -(buttonDelete.offsetWidth), max = 0,
 moveX = 0, startX = 0, added = 0, speed, friction = 0;

 hammer.on('panstart', function() {
 message.style[transitionStyle] = 'none';
 });

 hammer.on('panleft panright', function(e) {

 moveX = startX + e.deltaX;

 if (moveX < min) {
    friction = startX > min ? min/1.5 : startX;
    moveX = friction + (e.deltaX/3);
 }

 if (moveX <= max) {
    message.style[transformStyle] = 'translateX(' + moveX + 'px)';
 }

 });

 hammer.on('panend', function(e) {

 speed = .2 / (Math.abs(e.velocityX) + 1);

 added += e.deltaX;

 if (added < min/2) {
    startX = min;
 }
 else if (added > Math.abs(min/2)) {
    startX = max;
 }

 message.style[transitionStyle] = 'all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out';
 message.style[transformStyle] = 'translateX(' + startX + 'px)';

 added = 0;

 });

 function prefix() {

 var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, ''),
    pre = (Array.prototype.slice
        .call(styles)
        .join('')
        .match(/-(moz|webkit|ms)-/) || (styles.OLink === '' && ['', 'o'])
    )[1];

 return pre[0].toUpperCase() + pre.substr(1);

 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with the selector.

```
// grab ONE .message element
 message = document.querySelector('.message')

// grab ALL .message elements
 message = document.querySelectorAll('.message')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use querySelectotAll instead of querySelector. As well as noticed that you having two list instead of one. You need to have only one messages ul and have message li both in that ul.

Code

```
   <div class="wrapper">
 null   <ul class="messages">
    <li>
        <div class="message">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <time datetime="2014-08-22">Friday</time>
        </div>
        <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="message">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <time datetime="2014-08-22">Friday</time>
        </div>
        <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried this. For some reason, it's not working. I've updated the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPQBWj as you can see, following your recommendations, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user974725: In your codepen it saying Hammer is undefined.